# Back button js slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I'm not familiare with js and I am trying to make a slider witch contains html divs with animation. This is the js I use:

```
$(function(){
// find all slides
var slides = $('.main-slide');
// starting index
var i = 0;
// click listener
$('#main-slider-next').click(function(){
// find next index
// i + 1 or 0 if end of slides
i = ++i % slides.length;
// scroll to that index
$('.slider-wrapper').animate(
  {'left' : -(slides.eq(i).position().left)},
  1000
);
});
});
```

The code contains a next-slide button, but I am wondering how to make a previous-slide button with js. Does anyone have a clue how I can make that?

Comment: can you put this to jsfiddle?

Comment: The code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FkkF4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quite easy. try:

```
$('#main-slider-previous').click(function() {
    $('.slider-wrapper').animate({
        'left': '+=100%'
    },1000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use some simple jQuery slider e.g http://www.basic-slider.com/ (or more advanced http://unslider.com/)
All you have to do is to change animation type settings:

```
animtype : 'fade',
```

to

```
animtype : 'slide',
```

And you're ready to go ;).